# displaying selected grid image in Full Screen and the code for this needs to be in the MainActivity class as shown below

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GridView gridView;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    adapter.imageLoader.stopThread();
    gridView.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}


public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};



private String[] mStrings={
        "http://www.globaltvbc.com/uploadedImages/Global_News/Content/Wallpaper.jpeg",
        "http://cdn.windows7themes.net/themes/halo-3-hd-wallpaper.jpg",
   };
}
```

The question is i want to display the item on the gridview and display the item in full screen.I want to include any code to display the gridview item in full screen to be in the same class as MainActivity.I dont want my code to be in a new class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to load the full screen on the same activity then you should use popup window for displaying the image.

or the best solution is implement onItemClickListener on your main activity and on click get the item by position and pass the image url to next activityfor loading it there.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity implement OnItemClickListener{} .... then add unimplemented method which look like ................public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
   int position, long id) {

  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), your_Activity.class);
  i.putExtra("image", your_array[position]);
  
  startActivity(i);

 }

Comment: nope not working still if i click on a item in gridview iam not able to enlarge tat item

Comment: First tell me this, what are you doing to load images in a grid view?

Comment: make a custom adapter extending base adapter 
then set onItemClickListener on your GridView

Comment: yeup i have build my own custom adapter called lazy adapter extending base adapter i loaded the images from the url in the grid view and i just want to enlarge the image in the gridview in watever form tats it kindly help

Comment: just coz i cant paste the full code here i have just shown u the main activity code here

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you my code edit this according to your need
|main Activity

```
package com.mypack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class GridViewActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {



    List<RowItem4> rowItems;

    private GridView gridView;

    private Button galleryButton;

    private Button shareButton;
    private String[] mStringArray;
    public static final Integer[] partyid = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 18, 19, 20 };
    int i = 1;
    private String xml;
    String output = "";

    /*private static final String NAMESPACE = "";
    private static final String URL = "";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "";*/


    private int pos;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private int galleryId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        pos = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);
        galleryId = i.getIntExtra("galleryId", 0);

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(GridViewActivity.this, "",
                "Loading...");
        Thread myThread = new Thread() {

            private GridViewAdapter adapter;

            public void run() {
                getImages();

                rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem4>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length; i++) {
                    RowItem4 item = new RowItem4(mStringArray[i]);
                    rowItems.add(item);
                }
                // LoadImageFromURL(""
                // + output);
                adapter = new GridViewAdapter(GridViewActivity.this, rowItems);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        try {

                            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(GridViewActivity.this);

                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (final Exception ex) {
                            Log.i("---", "Exception in thread");
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        myThread.start();

        setUpView();

    }

    private void getImages() {
        final String envelope = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                + "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" "
                + "xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" "
                + "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" "
                + "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\""
                + " xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" "
                + "xmlns:tns=\"urn:registerwsdl\">" + "<SOAP-ENV:Body>"
                + "<tns:register " + "xmlns:tns=\"urn:registerwsdl\">"
                + "<galleryid xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">" + galleryId
                + "</galleryid>" + "<partyid xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">"
                + partyid[pos] + "</partyid>" + "</tns:register>" +

                // "</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>",Name,Email,Password,Status,Type,Date];
                "</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

        System.out.println("------------" + envelope);

        CallWebService(URL, SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

            NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("response");
            for (int j = 0; j < nl1.getLength(); j++) {

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("url");

                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

                    Node node = nl.item(i);

                    myList.add(node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

                }
            }
            mStringArray = new String[myList.size()];
            mStringArray = myList.toArray(mStringArray);

            for (int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length; i++) {
                Log.d("string is", (mStringArray[i]));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

    }

    String CallWebService(String url, String soapAction, String envelope) {
        final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // request parameters

        HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 20000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 25000);
        // set parameter
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpClient.getParams(), true);

        // POST the envelope
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        // add headers
        httppost.setHeader("soapaction", soapAction);
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        String responseString = "";
        try {

            // the entity holds the request
            HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(envelope);
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Response handler

            ResponseHandler<String> rh = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
                // invoked when client receives response

                public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

                    // get response entity
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    // read the response as byte array
                    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
                    byte[] b = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);

                    // write the response byte array to a string buffer
                    out.append(new String(b, 0, b.length));

                    return out.toString();
                }
            };

            responseString = httpClient.execute(httppost, rh);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("exception", e.toString());
        }

        xml = responseString.toString();
        // close the connection
        System.out.println("xml file ------" + xml);
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (i == 2) {

            if (galleryButton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                galleryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                shareButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            } else {
                galleryButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            i = 0;
        }
        i++;
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return false;

    }

    /*
     * public OnTouchListener touch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
     * 
     * public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     * //System.out.println("onTouch       =============-----------"); if
     * (galleryButton.getVisibility() == v.VISIBLE) {
     * galleryButton.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
     * 
     * shareButton.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
     * 
     * } else { galleryButton.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
     * 
     * shareButton.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
     * 
     * } return false; } };
     */
    private void setUpView() {

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        galleryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gallery_button);

        shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);

        // relativeLayout1.setOnTouchListener(touch);

    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowImageActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("image", mStringArray[position]);
        i.putExtra("galleryId", galleryId);
        startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

RowItem4 Object Class

```
package com.mypack;

public class RowItem4 {
    private String imageId;

    public String getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(String imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public RowItem4(String mStringArray) {
        this.imageId = mStringArray;

    }

}
```

GridViewAdapter extending BaseAdapter

```
package com.mypack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;





import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



    Context context;
    List<RowItem4> rowItems;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private Drawable d;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem4> rowItems) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = rowItems;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        public int position;


    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return rowItems.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return rowItems.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_image_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();


            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        RowItem4 rowItem = (RowItem4) getItem(position);

        holder.position = position;
        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(position,holder);

        task.execute(new String[] { ""+rowItem.getImageId() });


        //holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
        return convertView;
    }

    /*private Drawable LoadImageFromURL(String url)
    {
    try
    {
    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
    d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
    return d;
    }catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    return null;
    }
    }*/


    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private int mPosition;
        private ViewHolder mHolder;
        public GetXMLTask(int position, ViewHolder holder) {
            mPosition = position;
            mHolder = holder;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Bitmap map = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                map = downloadImage(url);
            }
            return map;
        }

        // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (mHolder.position == mPosition)
            {
            mHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
        }

        // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
        private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream stream = null;
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

            try {
                stream = getHttpConnection(url);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                        decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
        private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                throws IOException {
            InputStream stream = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is if you want to load the image on second activity,and if you want to load image on the same activity just add the code for adding popup window in the main activity. I think now it is clear

Comment: awesum thank u so much it helpd me a lot nw iam able to display

Comment: great if you were helped then please accept the answer and up-vote it